# numerical integration of equation obtained by ParametricNDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

I am trying to find a definite integral of the solution obtained using `ParametricNDSolve` (i.e. `y[x,a,b]`) from 0 to 1 and plot the obtained solution in two variables (i.e. a,b) with a.
Can you please suggest me a solution for the same as my equation is given by

```
ParametricNDSolve[{Cos[y[x]]*y''[x]*y'[x] + Sin[y[x]]*y'''[x] - 
 Sin[y[x]]*y'[x]*y'''[x] + Cos[y[x]]*y''''[x] + 
 4*a*(Sin[y[x]])*(Cos[y[x]])^3 - a*(Sin[y[x]])*(Cos[y[x]])^2 + 
 b*Sin[y[x]]*Cos[y[x]] == 0, y[0] == 0, y''[1] == 0, y'[1] == 0, 
 y'''[1] == -1*a*(Cos[y[1]])}, y, {x, 0, 1}, {a, b}]
```

all I want is a plot of the integral of `Sin[y[x]]` from 0 to 1 with a and b.

Answer (score 3):

One can integrate an expression within an `NDSolve`/`ParametricNDSolve` command. To integrate `Sin[y[x]]`, use the DE `u'[x] == Sin[y[x]]`.

```
psol = ParametricNDSolve[
  {Cos[y[x]]*y''[x]*y'[x] + Sin[y[x]]*y'''[x] - 
     Sin[y[x]]*y'[x]*y'''[x] + Cos[y[x]]*y''''[x] + 
     4*a*(Sin[y[x]])*(Cos[y[x]])^3 - a*(Sin[y[x]])*(Cos[y[x]])^2 + 
     b*Sin[y[x]]*Cos[y[x]] == 0, y[0] == 0, y''[1] == 0, y'[1] == 0, 
   y'''[1] == -1*a*(Cos[y[1]]),
   u'[x] == Sin[y[x]], u[0] == 0},
  {y, u}, {x, 0, 1}, {a, b}];

Plot3D[u[a, b][1] /. psol // Evaluate, {a, 0, 3}, {b, 0, 3}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure I understand your question correctly. Do these commands do what you want?

```
Plot[y[2, 3][x] /. sol, {x, 0, 1}]

plPoints = 
 Table[With[{f = Sin[y[a, b][x]] /. sol}, 
   NIntegrate[f, {x, 0, 1}]], {a, 0, 3, 0.1}, {b, 0, 3, 0.1}]

ListPointPlot3D[plPoints]
```

[image]